# How do I can view what is really inside an *.asi file?

Tags: file, view

I have a file with `.asi` extension working as a plug-in of another program, and I wanna to see what's inside that file so I can understand how this plug-in works.

I tried to open my file with some programs such as File Viewer Plus and Notepad++ but I only see a series of strange characters. How do I can see what's inside my file?

Comment: As a plug-in of which program exactly? The data is encoded, hence the weird characters.

Comment: Probably the file is a binary file. You wont be able to view its contents using text editors. Though sometimes, some file formats do have a text in header section, which are readable in the text editors.

Comment: The .asi file suffix is used by assembly language header files which is used by Borland Assembler application. You can view it by (Turbo C or Borland C++ tools) or by by hexadecimal editor.